# Why comparison of array values only matches most recently entered object value?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, if I enter a value in the textbox, it's supposed to return something. i.e.; entering 'PA' returns 'Pennsylvania'. But if I enter 'AZ', it returns my else statement.

**How do I change this so that it checks the value against any value entered and displays the result properly?**

```js
const states = [
  {
    abbreviated: 'AZ',
    state: 'Arizona'
  }, {
    abbreviated: 'PA',
    state: 'Pennsylvania'
  }
];

function searchState() {
  let txt = searchTxt.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var abbreviatedState = states[i];
    if (txt == abbreviatedState.abbreviated) {
      output.textContent = abbreviatedState.state;
    } else {
      output.textContent = 'Uh, oh! We don\'t know that one!';
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", ()=>searchState());
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" placeholder="State Abbreviation?"/>

<button class="search">Search</button>

<h4>State Of: <span id="output"></span></h4>
```

Comment: you loop through states from start to finish, unconditionally, so the last comparison is the last result for `output.textContent =` regardless of the previous comparisons - perhaps you need to stop the loop once the condition is true - that's what a programmer would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the loop to the end, and only assign `Uh oh` if nothing is found. To make the logic easier, use `.find` instead of a for loop.

```js
const states = [
  {
    abbreviated: 'AZ',
    state: 'Arizona'
  }, {
    abbreviated: 'PA',
    state: 'Pennsylvania'
  }
];

function searchState() {
  const txt = searchTxt.value;
  const foundState = states.find(state => state.abbreviated === txt);
  output.textContent = foundState
    ? foundState.state
    : 'Uh, oh! We don\'t know that one!'
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", ()=>searchState());
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" placeholder="State Abbreviation?"/>

<button class="search">Search</button>

<h4>State Of: <span id="output"></span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes into the `else` block even if it goes into `if` once. I've refactored the code to set "uh oh" as the default value, only searches for `if` and `break`s out once found.

```js
const states = [{
  abbreviated: 'AZ',
  state: 'Arizona'
}, {
  abbreviated: 'PA',
  state: 'Pennsylvania'
}];

function searchState() {
  let txt = searchTxt.value;
  output.textContent = 'Uh, oh! We don\'t know that one!';
  for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var abbreviatedState = states[i];
    if (txt == abbreviatedState.abbreviated) {
      output.textContent = abbreviatedState.state;
      break;
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", () => searchState());
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" placeholder="State Abbreviation?" />

<button class="search">Search</button>

<h4>State Of: <span id="output"></span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you continue searching event after `AZ` state is found and it goes into `else` later.

```js
const states = [{
  abbreviated: 'AZ',
  state: 'Arizona'
}, {
  abbreviated: 'PA',
  state: 'Pennsylvania'
}];

function searchState() {
  let txt = searchTxt.value;
  console.log(txt);
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');
  for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var abbreviatedState = states[i];
    if (txt == abbreviatedState.abbreviated) {
      output.textContent = abbreviatedState.state;
      break;
    } else {
      output.textContent = 'Uh, oh! We don\'t know that one!';
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener("click", () => searchState());
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" placeholder="State Abbreviation?" />

<button class="search">Search</button>

<h4>State Of: <span id="output"></span></h4>
```